# How to re-render the same component after deleting using react and redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

code for reference

```
//Component
delete = (id) => {
    this.props.deleteContentItem(id, this.props.history)
}

//action.js
export const deleteContentItem = (id, history) => dispatch => {
    axios.delete(`${API_ROOT}/mcenter/admin/delete/${id}`)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: DELETE_CONTENT,
                payload: res.data
            })
            history.push('/mcenter')
        })
        .catch(err =>
            dispatch({
                type: GET_ERRORS,
                payload: err.response.data
            })
        );
}
```

I'm in `/mcenter` URL and needs to refresh the same page after delete action.

**My Problem is:**

After deleting It is not re-rendering the component.

Any kind help will much appreciated.

Comment: for what  `history.push('/mcenter')` is used ? is that any purpose for that ?

Comment: Because it is not re-rendering so I tried to force that to navigate

Answer (score 0):

```
export const deleteContentItem = (id, history) => dispatch => {
    axios.delete(`${API_ROOT}/mcenter/admin/delete/${id}`)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: DELETE_CONTENT,
                payload: res.data
            })
           this.getsomedata();//get any data for your page inside then
        })
        .catch(err =>
            dispatch({
                type: GET_ERRORS,
                payload: err.response.data
            })
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you just need to setState , where the state is the returned data or error ?

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for you. I also had the same problem those days. Anyway, one of my friend told me that make everything immutable is the solution. The problem is not in the action. You have to do some changes in reducers.

```
import { List } from 'immutable';

export default function (state = {loading:false}, action) {
switch (action.type) {
     case 'DELETE_CONTENT':
        let currentProjects = List(state.Plist)
        let index = currentProjects.findIndex(i=>i.ProjectId===action.payload)
        let newProjectList = currentProjects.splice(index,1).toJS();
        return { ...state, Plist: newProjectList ,loading:false};
     default:
        return state;
}
```

}

Use this kind of approach.